# RSS reader with tagging of individual posts

Tags: ios, rss

Is there an RSS reader (ideally a website / iPhone app combo) that allows individual posts to be tagged? Most seem to allow "starring", but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Not just an RSS reader but a much greater app that meets your requirements too: [DEVONthink](http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/devonthink/overview.html).